# Strange characters render

Tags: c#, html, css, google-chrome, model-view-controller

I have a very rare issue in my page. This is my code:

```
<ul>
             <li><a id="menu_option_Home" target="_self" href="" class="">Inicio</a></li>
             <li><a id="menu_option_Customers" target="_self" href="/List/Clients/Display" class="">Contactos</a></li>
             <li><a id="menu_option_Deals" target="_self" href="" class="">Ventas</a></li>
             <li><a id="menu_option_Cases" target="_self" href="" class="active">Casos</a></li>
             <li><a id="menu_option_Project" target="_self" href="" class="">Proyectos</a></li>
             <li><a id="menu_option_Products" target="_self" href="" class="">Productos</a></li>
             <li><a id="menu_option_Contents" target="_self" href="" class="">Archivos</a></li>
        <li class="sum-menu-container">
            <a href="" id="e-store_menu">Mi tienda</a>
            <div class="sub-menu-wrap" style="display: none;">
                <ul>                       
                        <li><a id="menu_option_MyStore" target="_blank" href="" class="">Ver</a></li>
                             <li><a id="menu_option_MyStore" target="_self" href="" class="">Editar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

But, when I load the page, at least on chrome, sometimes I see it like this:
[image: error]

The strange thing is that when I change whatever I change it starts to render it ok. For example if I change the size of the chrome window or change the any part of the css file, the words are rendered fine.

Does anyone suffer the same issue? 
If you need any other clue let me know
Thanks!

Comment: Please try adding charset `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`

Comment: I've already have this line in my code. <meta charset="utf-8"> Is it the same?

Comment: Can you change the active item to see if it will be rendered right?

Comment: @MárcioGonzalez yes. If I remove the "active" class it renders OK also. Another thing is that if I change for example one word it starts rendering OK. I mean, if I change "Inicio" for "Inicios" it will render OK. Another thing is that if I select and copy a wrong word and paste in notepad it is the right word. I mean, if I copy "Jojdjp" and paste it in notepad it will paste "Inicio".

Comment: This is odd.
In this link http://pt.slideshare.net/citic/faro-de-vigo-11-agosto-2013-25-proyectos-innovadores-en-salud under "Transcript" text the text is similar to yours. I'm looking for a fix.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted this in other browsers, also another machine or even mobile version of chrome?

If so and the result is consistent I would highly recommend alerting google to this issue and providing them with all details accumulated so far.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en

Comment: I only could reproduce it in other machine with chrome. Didn't test it on mobile but I did on others browsers without this issue. Thanks for the answer, perhaps I will send them the issue later

Comment: if you can post the site online I can run a chrome sanity check on it using online & beta chrome components. Would be good to see the issue replicated and check for any console reporting.  My feeling is its a rendering issue within chrome